# Android: Encoding a bitmap in byte64 creates a memory error, when trying to upload to php file on server

Tags: php, android, bitmap, encode

Hey so like the title says, I am trying to encode a photo taken from an android camera that immediately gets uploaded by sending a post request to a php file stored on a server.

I am getting a URI too long response back from the server after pasting the encoded image into word it spans across over 155 pages. It's way too long for sending over a POST request, yet this is how we have done it in the past.

Edit: I wanted to add that the number of characters in the url I am sending is over 972,000, way over the limit of any browser.

Any help would be awesome!

Here is the code that is doing the encoding, maybe I am not doing something right.

```
    fun uploadPhoto(photo: Bitmap) {
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 2, stream)
    val byte_arr = stream.toByteArray()
    val encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0)    ...
```

Comment: There is no code that uploads or posts anything.

Comment: `I wanted to add that the number of characters in the url I am sending is over 972,000`. If you put it in the url it is considered a GET request. But you were talking about POST.

Comment: I am using retrofit to append the queries to the back of a url for a php script on a server

Comment: If you want that code its alot, but I can make a few posts to do it I suppose